# Google spreadsheets - how to handle duration: store and use in calculations?

Tags: google-sheets, duration

I've got a lot of "duration" values - basically a race duration - in a format m:ss.millis [4:03.810 for example].
Currently GS handles it as text, but I would like to use those values for comparison and create some statistics.

Is this possible? I have read this: [How to format a duration as HH:mm in the new Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710299/how-to-format-a-duration-as-hhmm-in-the-new-google-sheets) but even though I have created a custom formats like:

[image: duration custom time format]

or

[image: custom time format]

but neither with one nor with another I cannot use those values for calculations. GS always complains about the values beeing stored as text.

I guess I'm just doing something wrong, but I definitely need to be able to provide values in this format and be able to use them in calculations.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regret that `Duration` seems to be a useless abomination and Sheets *appears* to offer no relatively easy way to convert text representation to values. Pending a better answer I suggest you convert all your durations as below:

```
=(left(A1,find(":",A1)-1)+right(A1,6)/60)/1440
```

format as Number:

```
mm:ss.000
```

and then apply your formulae.

(Change `,` to `;` if required by your locale.)

A shorter formula might be used to cajole [TIMEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350) to work by including an hour value of `0`:

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:"&A1)
```

---

A happy coincidence brought me back here because only very recently have I found that Google Sheets *does* offer a way to convert Text to Number (or I was having another aberration when I claimed otherwise). However, this still seems not to apply to Duration. Maybe there is yet hope though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope for something cleaner, but this is good enough for now. I will have to convert all of the values and copy them because running this formula all the time on the whole data set would kill the spreadsheet ;)