# Suggest me to customize excel with date formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, timestamp

[image: Customized Excel Time Sheet For Employees]

In the image attached, I need employees to manually enter login and logout times in the format `(HH:MM AM/PM)` only. And In the column E I need a formula to calculate hours and minutes of duration in between.

I have tried with `=text(D2-C2,"h:mm")` formula and when I applied the same to all the columns, they're updating with existing empty cells and resulting 00:00 in the E column.

I only need to update column E only when C and D column values are updated.

Can someone please help me in this regard? I need time frame as 12Hour format.

Comment: You should consider controlling their input : if they make a typing error such as "92:0" instead of "9:20" - data validation can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=IF(AND(C1<>"",D1<>""),D1-C1,"")` in your `No Of Hours` column to calculate only if `Log In Time` and `Log Out Time` are filled.

For formatting, you can use `Custom Format` - `h:mm` for the `No Of Hours` column.

Comment: Thank You Arul. But I am unable to find "custom format" as you mentioned, as I am working on Google Sheets(Online).

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710299/how-to-format-a-duration-as-hhmm-in-the-new-google-sheets) helps.

Answer (score 1):

1, Try not to convert real time to text.

2. Use this formula in F2 then fill down. `=E2-D2+AND(E2<D2, E2>0)` This should also work if the shift spans midnight.
3. Use this custom number format `hh:mm_);;;` on the cells.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hello Heeped.. There's a problem with the answer, as it calculates the value even if the values are not provided.

Comment: You write an IF with AND to make sure there are both values.