# Google Sheets: Which time format to use to display and convert hours to minutes?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am having issues understanding which time format to use to show Over Time in minutes and hour format.

I have used "Elapsed minutes' and that worked fine, until I had to deduct the times (J column).

It gives me a number '-85860', and it should give me '480'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzYdO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a duration as HH:mm in the new Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710299/how-to-format-a-duration-as-hhmm-in-the-new-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the 60 in as 1:00 (one hour), otherwise it will be taken as 60 days (=86400 minutes).

[image]