# How to format a number as HH:MM in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have Data set in google sheets that shows time spent log for a user in SECONDS.
For example,
Name (text)   | Time Spent (number)
user A        | 86400

How can format the time spent field as 24:00:00

Followed so many format related articles but all I am getting is 2073600:00:00 or similar weird numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to first divide by 86400, then set Format > Number > Duration. This is because the duration is evaluated in days (a value of `1` is formatted as 24 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds).

Example: if cell A1 contains the value of "3600" (seconds), you can display it as a duration in A2 by setting the value of A2 to "=A1/86400", then changing the format of A2 to Duration. A2 will display a duration of 1 hour in the default format.

See also [How to format a duration as HH:mm in the new Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710299/how-to-format-a-duration-as-hhmm-in-the-new-google-sheets) for custom formatting of the duration.

Comment: so, to summarize, I can not get a direct formatting on the returned result. rather I need to add an extra column to get the desired formatting, right?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A2:A5/86400, "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

[image]